# Firebase query returns {$value:null} where there is an array - Ionic/Angular2/AngularFire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, null

The below code is supposed to get an object from firebase, an `array`.

```
this.item2 = this.af.object('/profiles/' + this.username + '/followers');
    this.subscription5 = this.item2.subscribe(item => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(item) + "      followers number 98989899889");
      if(Object.keys(item)[0] == '$value') {
        this.followers = 0;
      }
      else {
        this.followers = item.length;
      }
    })
```

This is the structure of my firebase database:

```
"profiles" : {
"Jencuts" : {
    "address" : "34 school st dedham ma",
    "bio" : "I love cuts. Cuts are my jam i am jencuts who are you?",
        "email" : "Hhghjjj@7654.com",
        "followers" : [ {
          "Jencuts" : "gxPYJNXcOagJr7gxNzPLtUY9aZF2"
        } ],
        "password" : "Kjhvjjjjbcv",
        "price" : "$$$$",
        "rating" : {
          "five" : 0,
          "four" : 0,
          "one" : 0,
          "three" : 0,
          "two" : 0
        },
        "username" : "Jencuts"
      },

      ....
```

`Jencuts` is the username (`this.username`).

It should be returning the `followers` array instead it says it doesn't find anything and returns `{$value:null}`.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to put my code in the block that gets the username from `Storage` when the page loads.